# How prove that limits of $x_n$, $y_n$ exist?

Tags: limits

Let $x_{n}$, $y_{n}\ge 0$ satisfy the equations

> $$\large\begin{cases}
> x^{\frac{4n+5}{n}}_{n}+3x_{n}+y_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}\\
> y^{\frac{n+2}{n}}_{n}+4x_{n}+3y_{n}=4-\dfrac{1}{n}
> \end{cases}$$

Show that the limits

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n},\lim_{n\to\infty}y_{n}$$

exist, and find their values.

Answer (score 2):

I call your two relations (1) and (2).
Let us show first that $(x_n) \to 0$. It will suffice to show that for any $n$,
$$
x_n \leq \frac{4}{5n}  \tag{*}
$$

If $x_n \le \frac{1}{3n}$ then (*) is obvious.  So assume $x_n \ge \frac{1}{3n}$. We then have, by (1)
$$
y_n=1+\frac{1}{n}-x_n^{\frac{4n+5}{n}}-3x_n \leq 1+\frac{1}{n}-3x_n \leq 1 \tag{3}
$$

Now (2) forces us to have

$$
(4-\frac{1}{n}-4x_n-3y_n)^n=y_n^{n+2} \leq 1 \tag{4}
$$

We deduce

$$
1 \geq 4-\frac{1}{n}-4x_n-3y_n=4-\frac{1}{n}-4x_n-3\big(1+\frac{1}{n}-x_n^{\frac{4n+5}{n}}-3x_n)\big)=1-\frac{4}{n}-5x_n-3x_n^{\frac{4n+5}{n}} \tag{5}
$$

and hence 
$$
5x_n+3x_n^{\frac{4n+5}{n}} \leq \frac{4}{n} \tag{6}
$$
This proves (*).

Now we know that $x_n \to 0$, we deduce $y_n \to 1$ by (1), and this finishes the problem.

Comment: If $(x_n, y_n)$ exists!

Comment: One can show $(x_n,y_n)$ exists, but that’s a separate question in my view.